# How to make a condition so the commands are executed only when the activity is open from a specific activity?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

My app crashes when a button to open an activity is pressed because there are some commands to import data from an unopen activity. That's why I was thinking about a condition. Ideas?

JAVA (The activity from where data are imported):

```
package com.exemple.android.calendar;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.InputFilter;
import android.text.Spanned;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

public class NewEventActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //step 1.A:create objects

    public EditText DayEditText;
    public EditText MonthEditText;
    public EditText YearEditText;
    public EditText StartingHourEditText;
    public EditText StartingMinuteEditText;
    public EditText EndingHourEditText;
    public EditText EndingMinuteEditText;
    public EditText Title;
    public RadioGroup answer1;
    public Button NewEventButton;

    int day, month, year, s_hour, s_min, e_hour, e_min;
    String title;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.new_event_page);


        //Step 1.B: assign objects

        DayEditText = findViewById(R.id.DayEditText);
        MonthEditText = findViewById(R.id.MonthEditText);
        YearEditText = findViewById(R.id.YearEditText);
        StartingHourEditText = findViewById(R.id.StartingHourEditText);
        StartingMinuteEditText = findViewById(R.id.StartingMinuteEditText);
        EndingHourEditText = findViewById(R.id.EndingHourEditText);
        EndingMinuteEditText = findViewById(R.id.EndingMinuteEditText);
        Title = findViewById(R.id.TitleEditText);
        answer1 = findViewById(R.id.Answer1);
        NewEventButton = findViewById(R.id.CreateEventButton);

        DayEditText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new MinMaxFilter("0", "31")});
        MonthEditText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new MinMaxFilter("0", "12")});
        YearEditText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new MinMaxFilter("0", "2030")});
        StartingHourEditText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new MinMaxFilter("0", "23")});
        StartingMinuteEditText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new MinMaxFilter("0", "59")});
        EndingHourEditText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new MinMaxFilter("0", "23")});
        EndingMinuteEditText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new MinMaxFilter("0", "59")});
        //Step 2: get data into variables

        //Step 2.B: get data and assign
        //PROBLEM: If we just extract, the code won't be run because there's nothing to extract yet. We need a conditional.
        //SOLUTION: Create a condition for pressing the button, and then extract the variables when the button is pressed.


        //TODO: Create the variable and method for chosen option at RadioGroup
        TextWatcher dayTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                day = Integer.parseInt(DayEditText.getText().toString());
            }
        };
        TextWatcher monthTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                month = Integer.parseInt(MonthEditText.getText().toString());
            }
        };
        TextWatcher yearTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                year = Integer.parseInt(YearEditText.getText().toString());
            }
        };
        TextWatcher titleTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                title = Title.getText().toString();
            }
        };
        TextWatcher s_hourTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                s_hour = Integer.parseInt(StartingHourEditText.getText().toString());
            }
        };
        TextWatcher s_minTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                s_min = Integer.parseInt(StartingMinuteEditText.getText().toString());
            }
        };
        TextWatcher e_minTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                e_min = Integer.parseInt(EndingMinuteEditText.getText().toString());
            }
        };
        TextWatcher e_hourTextWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                e_hour = Integer.parseInt(EndingHourEditText.getText().toString());
            }
        };

        DayEditText.addTextChangedListener(dayTextWatcher);
        MonthEditText.addTextChangedListener(monthTextWatcher);
        YearEditText.addTextChangedListener(yearTextWatcher);
        Title.addTextChangedListener(titleTextWatcher);
        StartingMinuteEditText.addTextChangedListener(s_minTextWatcher);
        StartingHourEditText.addTextChangedListener(s_hourTextWatcher);
        EndingMinuteEditText.addTextChangedListener(e_minTextWatcher);
        EndingHourEditText.addTextChangedListener(e_hourTextWatcher);


        NewEventButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                answer1.clearCheck();
                Intent agendaPageGoing = new Intent(NewEventActivity.this, AgendaActivity.class);
                agendaPageGoing.putExtra("DayExtra", ""+day);
                agendaPageGoing.putExtra("MonthExtra", ""+month);
                agendaPageGoing.putExtra("YearExtra", ""+year);
                agendaPageGoing.putExtra("TitleExtra", ""+title);
                agendaPageGoing.putExtra("EndingHExtra", ""+e_hour);
                agendaPageGoing.putExtra("EndingMinExtra", ""+e_min);
                agendaPageGoing.putExtra("StartHExtra", ""+s_hour);
                agendaPageGoing.putExtra("StartMinExtra", ""+s_min);
                startActivity(agendaPageGoing);

            }
        });

    }


}
```

JAVA (Activity which is opened by the button and imports data)

```
package com.exemple.android.calendar;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CalendarView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.sql.Date;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class AgendaActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int day2,year2,month2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.agenda_page);

        final Button showDetails = findViewById(R.id.SeeEventsButton);
        CalendarView calendar = findViewById(R.id.calendarView);
        TextView events = findViewById(R.id.detailsShowTextView);

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        day2 = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        year2=cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        month2=cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);

        calendar.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
           @Override
           public void onSelectedDayChange(@NonNull CalendarView calendarView, int year, int month, int day) {
               year2 = year;
               month2 = month;
               day2=day;
           }
       });



        int day, month, year, s_hour, s_min, e_hour, e_min; String title;

        Intent intent = getIntent();

        String day_s=intent.getStringExtra("DayExtra");
        day=Integer.parseInt(day_s);

        String month_s=intent.getStringExtra("MonthExtra");
        month=Integer.parseInt(month_s);

        String year_s=intent.getStringExtra("YearExtra");
        year=Integer.parseInt(year_s);

        String s_s_hour=intent.getStringExtra("StartHExtra");
        s_hour=Integer.parseInt(s_s_hour);

        String s_s_min=intent.getStringExtra("StartMinExtra");
        s_min=Integer.parseInt(s_s_min);

        String s_e_hour=intent.getStringExtra("EndingHExtra");
        e_hour=Integer.parseInt(s_e_hour);

        String s_e_min=intent.getStringExtra("EndingMinExtra");
        e_min=Integer.parseInt(s_e_min);

        title =intent.getStringExtra("TitleExtra");


        showDetails.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
            //TODO: make the "if" for values
            // TODO: make arrays for values to create multiple entries
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please print logcat error for better understanding.

Comment: It's no use to show the logcat. In the Agenda Activity I import some data from the NewEventActivity. The problem is that when I go to Agenda Activity from the Main, without passing before through the NewEventActivity it crashes.

Comment: You shouldn't.  YOu should fix your architecture so that this activity isn't launched if it isn't valid, and so that it has a sane default if it is anyway.  Activities should be written such that they get all the data they need either in their own workflow, or is passed in via intent.

Comment: Ok! Super. Could you reformat the code?